# How to order link display based on total clicks with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, phpmyadmin

I have a webpage that contains links to outside websites. how do I change the ordering of the links based on total page clicks? as in, the most clicked link is at the top of the list, the second-most clicked is second in the list, etc.

I have all the links in a phpmyadmin database table, with a page_count column currently set at 0 for all the rows. i guess im trying to figure out how do I add 1 to a page_count cell when the corresponding link is clicked? and then how to sort the display of the links based on the page_count numbers?

Comment: Only two ways I could think is, add the links inside of a form that submits what link was clicked or setup an ajax function that triggers to send which link was clicked. The latter would fail if javascript was disabled in the browser. when retrieving the data, you could sort on query or upon receiving the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with displaying the links and putting their database IDs into `data-id` attribute, to get this:

```
<a href="link_1" data-id="1">
<a href="link_1" data-id="2">
<a href="link_1" data-id="3">
```

Then, I would use jQuery's `$.ajax()` to increase `page_count` value in the database:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'my_script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            link_id: $this.data('id')
        },
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

In **my_script.php** I would get the current status of `page_count` based on my `link_id` variable:

```
<php

    $clicked_id = $_POST['link_id'];

    /* Based on $clicked_id, use MySQL query to get the current page_count value
    Increase the value by 1
    Use another query to update the page_count value */

    echo "Success!";

?>
```

Note: I did not test it, but this is how I would try to achieve the goal.

More about jQuery's `$.ajax()`: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: what part of the ajax adds to the page count? and also, why exactly do we need to get the current status of page_count in the my_script.php?

Comment: `$.ajax()` function does not add anything. In this case, its purpose is to send the data asynchronously to the PHP script. And about the increasing, well, you first need to know what is the current page count for a specific link before you actually increase it by 1, right?

Comment: Incrementation has to take place in your PHP script. 1 - You pass the data from `$.ajax()` to PHP. 2 - You get the current page count from the database, increment the value, save the new value back in the database. 3 - You leave the script using `echo` and do other things on ajax `success` if you need

Answer (score 0):

First use AJAX to make a send a POST to a php file.
[AJAX POST](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

---

Than create a script that first read the value form database and than add one to it and save it back.

---

This is a syntax for your code to sort display.
SELECT sth FROM table ORDER BY count DESC
Fetch it and display starting from 0.